# \usepackage{enumitem} produces "Environment description undefined" error

Tags: errors, enumitem, standalone

If I run `pdflatex` on the following:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{upquote}
% \usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,chains,shapes,scopes}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I get no error. However, if I uncomment `\usepackage{enumitem}` then running `pdflatex` on the document produces the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment description undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.775 \renewenvironment{description}
                                    [1][]
?
```

Why is this, and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*From my comment to a proper answer. `:)`*

With the option `class=minimal`, you are telling `standalone` to use `minimal` as underlying class, which is not a "real" document class and does not have the `description` environment defined.

You can either use the `loadonly` option for `enumitem` which will load the package but the three lists are not redefined, or use the default `standalone` underlying class, which is `article`.

Comment: Related Question: [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-not-use-the-minimal-class).

Answer (score 3):

When using custom classes (`class=minimal`), the package can be declared this way:

```latex
\newcommand{\description}{}
\usepackage{enumitem}
```